# How to do query optimization. Current dashboard took more than 3 minutes to show up

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I am enhancing a dashboard which was built in that is taking a long time to query. However, I'm a newbie to SSDT and I have no idea where I should look.

I tried to remove the charts that might caused the problem, but no luck.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp1

SELECT HD.Incident_Number,HDA.log,HDA.Assigned_To,HD.Entry_ID,

DATEADD(hour, 14, DATEADD(day, 25567, HDA.Create_Date / (60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0) - 0.25)) AS MSC_submit_Date,
       CONCAT(FORMAT(DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hour, 14, DATEADD(day, 25567, HDA.Create_Date / (60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0) - 0.25))), '00'), ':', FORMAT(DATEPART(mi, DATEADD(hour, 14, DATEADD(day, 25567, HDA.Create_Date / (60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0) - 0.25))), '00'), ':', FORMAT(DATEPART(ss, DATEADD(hour, 14, DATEADD(day, 25567, HDA.Create_Date / (60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0) - 0.25))), '00')) AS Time

INTO #temp1
FROM HPD_Help_Desk HD LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    -- HPD_WorkLog AS HPD_WL ON HPD_WL.Incident_Number = HD.Incident_Number LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    --reference.dbo.SAP_worker AS rsw ON HD.Internet_E_mail = LOWER(rsw.micron_username) + '@micron.com' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    HPD_HelpDesk_AuditLogSystem AS HDA ON HD.Entry_ID = HDA.Original_Request_ID 
                    --SLM_Measurement AS SM ON HD.Incident_Number = SM.ApplicationUserFriendlyID  

WHERE 
(DATEADD(hour, 14, DATEADD(day, 25567, HDA.Create_date/ (60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0) - 0.25)) >= @Shift_start_time) 

NA
```

Comment: That `WHERE` clause is the problem, and I have no idea what it's trying to achieve. How do you divide a date (2017-06-01 / 2 = ????)? Then you're adding 25567 hours to that value, which is over 70 years. Explain the `WHERE` and we might be able to help you here.

Comment: Try to transform `(DATEADD(hour, 14, DATEADD(day, 25567, HDA.Create_date/ (60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0) - 0.25)) >= @Shift_start_time)` to one that does no operations on `HDA.Create_date` but on `@Shift_start_time` instead. As it's written now it's non-[sargable](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222053424/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 1):

Using date functions in the WHERE clause is killing index usage. There are plenty of articles on the web about that. You can easily google for that by searching for `SARG`. For example [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/).

So to make your query working faster you need to do following things:

- Create an index for `HPD_HelpDesk_AuditLogSystem` table. The easiest way for you could be check explain plan for that query and SSMS would probably suggest the index if it doesnt' exist
- Make the predicate in the `WHERE` clause SARGable. It's hard to understand what's the logic is there. But simply speaking, that you need to re-write it in a way where all the functions are used against the `@Shift_start_time` variable.

One more thing is that you can use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER` because you are using the joined table column as the predicate.